# How to compress a php file using PhpStorm or in other way?

Tags: php, phpstorm

I am using PhpStorm. I need to compress a PHP file in with PhpStorm. I have tried a lot with online php compressor but it seems to be not success. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to compress a php file"?

Comment: i have a php file eg:index.php . i have to compress it.

Comment: "i have to compress it" --- and what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

> if all you have is a hammer everything looks like a nail

In general it's not the actual PHP Code that is taking too long.

Check this before you are trying to win 0,01ms by compressing your PHP Code.

1. SQL

   - long running queries
   - number of queries
2. Server configuration
3. Bad Code (xdebug performance profiling)